# Get row count of tableA depending on existence of a FK in tableB

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get row count in `tableA` if and only if `rowA_x` does not have a `FK` pointing to `rowB_x` in `tableB`.

tableA:

```
id | id_tableB
```

tableB

```
id | ...
```

So basically the rows in `tableA` should only be counted if the column `id_tableA` does not exist as `id` in `tableB`.

Is there a *clean* way to do such counting. I have around ~500.000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several (not 100% sure about the MySQL syntax, so this might require some tweaking):

Subselect with NOT IN:

```
select count(*) from tableA where id_tableB not in (select id from tableB);
```

Subselect with NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from tableA a 
where NOT EXISTS (select null from tableB b where a.id_tableB = b.id);
```

OUTER JOIN:

```
 select count(*) from (
    select a.*, b.id as b_id
    from tableA a
    left join tableB b on a.id_tableB = b.id)
  where b_id IS NULL;
```

Which of these is the fastest depends on your data, but usually, a JOIN is more efficient than a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way I can think of doing this is using a sub-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableA
WHERE id_tableB NOT IN (
  SELECT id 
  FROM tableB
)
;
```

**Edit:**  However, upon further consideration, the below query may actually be more efficient as it uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than a sub-query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB B 
    ON A.id_tableB= B.id
WHERE B.id IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` structure.

If I understood well your question, your final query will look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tableB WHERE tableA.id = tableB.id_tableA)
```